# Pandas - Reversing and assigning column names not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with 6000 columns, one subset of it (1500 cols) has the column names incorrectly reversed.

I can pull out the subset like so:

```
orderbook.loc[:,'ask_price_1500':'ask_price_1'].columns
```

and get the cols:

```
Index(['ask_price_1500', 'ask_price_1499', 'ask_price_1498', 'ask_price_1497',
       'ask_price_1496', 'ask_price_1495', 'ask_price_1494', 'ask_price_1493',
       'ask_price_1492', 'ask_price_1491',
       ...
       'ask_price_10', 'ask_price_9', 'ask_price_8', 'ask_price_7',
       'ask_price_6', 'ask_price_5', 'ask_price_4', 'ask_price_3',
       'ask_price_2', 'ask_price_1'],
      dtype='object', length=1500)
```

Now reversing the columns is quite easy I can just add `[::-1]` to get the new order.

```
Index(['ask_price_1', 'ask_price_2', 'ask_price_3', 'ask_price_4',
       'ask_price_5', 'ask_price_6', 'ask_price_7', 'ask_price_8',
       'ask_price_9', 'ask_price_10',
       ...
       'ask_price_1491', 'ask_price_1492', 'ask_price_1493', 'ask_price_1494',
       'ask_price_1495', 'ask_price_1496', 'ask_price_1497', 'ask_price_1498',
       'ask_price_1499', 'ask_price_1500'],
      dtype='object', length=1500)
```

However when trying to assign these reversed columns with

```
orderbook.loc[:,'ask_price_1500':'ask_price_1'].columns = orderbook.loc[:,'ask_price_1500':'ask_price_1'].columns[::-1]
```

it has no effect and the column names do not change.

Any help is appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the ordering of those columns or do you only want to reassign the names without doing anything else?

Comment: Good question, just reassign the names.

Comment: Good question, just reassign the names.

Comment: If you are just trying to reassign the names you shouldn't need to use `.loc`. Instead, try getting the whole set of columns, adjust it the way you need and set it straight to your `orderbook.columns` (edit: just like @coldspeed answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a little sublist reversal and reassignment:

```
v = orderbook.columns.tolist()
# The index that comes first.
i = orderbook.columns.get_loc('ask_price_1500')
# The index that comes second.
j = orderbook.columns.get_loc('ask_price_1')
# Reverse list subslice.
v[i:j+1] = v[j:i-1:-1]
# Assign the result back to the DataFrame.
df.columns = v
```